# Persisting complex data on orientation change

Tags: android, persistence, orientation-changes

I was wondering what the best way is to store variables of a complex data type in Android. onSaveInstanceState() can only be used for simple data types like string, integer etc., but if I wanted so save something else, what could I do?

These are the methods I know of so far:

1. Save it in the database and restore it
2. Create a json and save the json-string in the database or shared preferences.
3. Use static variables (not recommended due to possible memory leaks and other unwanted behaviour)
4. Making it parceable

I am not satisfied with either one of the methods mentioned above, so I am looking for a different, more generic approach. For example if I wanted to save an ArrayList containing fragments, what could I do (let's not discuss why I would do that, and let's also pretend there's no such such as a fragmentmanager).

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you can make a class parcelable you can store the same as below in the same `OnsaveInstanceState`

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    try
    {


        outState.putParcelable("ListViewFragment", (Parcelable) mLeftMenuFragment);
        outState.putParcelable("ProductsGridFragment", (Parcelable) mProductsGridFragment);
        outState.putParcelable("ProductDetailsFragment", (Parcelable) mProductDetailsFragment);
        outState.putParcelable("FeaturedFragment", (Parcelable) mFeaturedFragment);
        outState.putParcelable("CategoryFragment", (Parcelable) mCategoryFragment);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        mLogger.error(Logger.ERROR_CODE_API, e);
    }
}
```

Get them back as below

```
if(savedInstanceState != null)
        {
            isFeaturedProduct = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("IsFeaturedProduct");
            mLeftMenuFragment = (LeftMenuFragment) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("ListViewFragment");
            mProductsGridFragment = (ProductListFragment) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("ProductsGridFragment");
            mProductDetailsFragment = (ProductDetailsFragment) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("ProductDetailsFragment");
            if(isFeatured)
                mFeaturedFragment = (FeaturedFragment) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("FeaturedFragment");
            else
                mCategoryFragment = (CategoryFragment) savedInstanceState.getParcelable("CategoryFragment");
            // mActionBar.setTitle(savedInstanceState.getString("ActionBarTitle"));
        }
        else
        {
            mLeftMenuFragment = new LeftMenuFragment();
            mProductsGridFragment = new ProductListFragment();
            mProductDetailsFragment = new ProductDetailsFragment();
            if(isFeatured)
            {
                mFeaturedFragment = new FeaturedFragment();
            }
            else
            {
                mCategoryFragment = new CategoryFragment();
            }
            mIsFeaturedClicked = true;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot to mention that I tried parceable already, but it still seems like a rather cumbersome approach, and I have to make each custom datatype parceable.
Is there really no other way? I mean, isn't orientation change common practice?!